# Упорядочить односвязный список. delphi/pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal

Необходимо упорядочить список: в начало положительные, затем 0, в конец отрицательные.
Сам код:

```
type
  TInfo = integer;
 
  PElem = ^TElem;
  TElem = record
      info: TInfo;
      next: PElem;
  end;

procedure AddR(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: integer); // адреса начала и конца списка и R
var ListC: PElem;  // текущий элемент списка
begin
   if ListN = nil then CreateList(ListN , ListK, r) // если список пуст
     else
       if r > 0 then AddFirst(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в начало
        else
         if r < 0 then AddLast(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в конец
           else
             begin // найти после какого
               ListC:=ListN; // с начала списка
               while (ListC^.next <> nil) and (ListC^.next^.info > 0) do
               ListC := ListC^.next;
              AddMedium(ListN, ListC, ListK, r); // добавить после текущего
             end;
```

Процедуры добавления в начало/конец/середину списка:

```
    procedure AddFirst(var ListN: PElem; ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
    var Elem: PElem;
    begin
      new(Elem);
      Elem^.info:=r;
      Elem^.next:=ListN;
      ListN:=Elem; // теперь он 1-ый
    end;
     
    // добавить новый элемент в конец
    procedure AddLast(ListN: PElem; var ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
    begin
      new(ListK^.next);
      ListK^.next^.info:=r;
      ListK^.next^.next:=nil;
      ListK:= ListK^.next;
    end;
     
    // добавить новый элемент в середину после ListC (не в конец)
    procedure AddMedium(ListN,ListC,ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
    var Elem: PElem;
    begin
      new(Elem);
      Elem^.info:=r;
      Elem^.next:=ListC^.next; // после него то, что было после ListC
      ListC^.next:=Elem; // а он сам после ListC
    end;

procedure CreateList(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: TInfo);
begin
  New(ListN);
  ListK:=ListN; // конец и начало совпадают
  ListN^.info:=r;
  ListN^.next:=nil;
end;
```

Нужно упорядочить список по правилу: в начале положительные, затем 0, в конец отрицательные, при этом их порядок их следования не должен меняться, т.е. дан список  `5, 0, 3, -9, 0, -8, 7` после его упорядочивания должно получиться так 5, 3, 7, 0, 0, -9, -8.

Проблема в том, что нули и отрицательные числа упорядочиваются в требуемом порядке, а положительные - в порядке, обратном требуемому. Например, при записи в список последовательности 1, 3, -4, 0, -5, 7 в списке будет последовательность 7, 3, 1, 0, -4, -5. В чём ошибка?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что это ошибка? У вас задача добавить положительные слева, а отрицательные справа. О том, что элементы внутри группы должны быть отсортированы - нет ни слова. Попробуйте на вход подать `7, 3, -4, 0, -5, 1` и у вас и для положительных слетит сортировка

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, возможно я неправильно сформулировал проблему. Для моего примера правильный список будет выглядеть так: `1, 3, 7, 0, -4, -5`

Comment: Почему не `7, 3, 1, 0, -4, -5` или `3, 7, 1, 0, -5, -4`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, задание такое...

Comment: Объясните логику задания. Положительные по возрастанию, а отрицательные по убыванию?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Нет, числа нужно упорядочить список по правилу: в начало положительные, затем 0, в конец отрицательные, при этом их порядок их следования не должен меняться, т.е. дан список ` 5, 0, 3, -9, 0, -8, 7` после его упорядочивания должно получиться так `5, 3, 7, 0, 0, -9, -8` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить исходный порядок для положительных чисел, вам нужно положительные числа вставлять не в начало списка, а после последнего положительного числа

```pascal
procedure AddR(var ListN, ListK: PElem; r: integer); // адреса начала и конца списка и R
var ListC: PElem;  // текущий элемент списка
begin
  if ListN = nil then
    CreateList(ListN, ListK, r) // если список пуст
  else if r < 0 then AddLast(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в конец
  else begin // добавить после последнего положительного
    if ListN^.info <= 0 then  // Если первый элемент не положительный
      AddFirst(ListN, ListK, r) // добавить в начало
    else begin
      ListC := ListN; // с начала списка
      while (ListC^.next <> nil) and (ListC^.next^.info > 0) do
        ListC := ListC^.next;
      AddMedium(ListN, ListC, ListK, r); // добавить после текущего
      if ListC = ListK then  // Если добавляли в конец списка
        ListK := ListC^.next;  // то сместить конец списка
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Для такого набора входных данных `-3, 4, 3, -3, 0, 3, -4, 0` выдает `-3, 3, 0, 0, -3, -4`, хотя должно `-3` переместить к отрицательным числам.

Comment: Еще и некоторых чисел нет в списке

Comment: Добавил createlist выше

Comment: Да, работает. Огромное Вам спасибо.

Comment: программа не работает на таком наборе входных данных `10, 0, 0, -12, 0`. Выдаёт `10, 0, -12`, вместо `10, 0, 0, 0, -12`

Comment: @wesbi Исправил. [Работает](https://onlinegdb.com/B1qo6lL4_)